# Error in Google Sheets Script when parsing XML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing, reddit

I have this function running in a Google Sheets script that pulls HTML from subreddits and returns them to a spreadsheet. It works for me some/most of the time, but other times I get an error "Could not parse text. (line 13)" which is the line with `var doc = Xml.parse(page, true);`. Any idea why this is happening or is this just a bug with Google Scripts? Here's the code that works...sometimes.

```
function getRedditHTML() {

  var entries_array = [];
  var subreddit_array = ['https://www.reddit.com/r/news/','https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/','https://www.reddit.com/r/science/'];

  for (var s = 0; s < subreddit_array.length; s++) {

    var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(subreddit_array[s]);

    //this is Line 13 that is breaking
    var doc = Xml.parse(page, true);

    var bodyHtml = doc.html.body.toXmlString();
    doc = XmlService.parse(bodyHtml);
    var root = doc.getRootElement();
    var entries = getElementsByClassName(root,'thing');

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

      var title = getElementsByClassName(entries[i],'title');
      title = XmlService.getRawFormat().format(title[1]).replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");

      var link = getElementsByClassName(entries[i],'comments');
      link = link[0].getAttribute('href').getValue();

      var rank = getElementsByClassName(entries[i],'rank');
      rank = rank[0].getValue();

      var likes = getElementsByClassName(entries[i],'likes');
      likes = likes[0].getValue();


      entries_array.push([rank, likes, title, link]);
    }
  }

  return entries_array.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return b[1] - a[1];
  });
}
```

Comment: Your script didn't work at all when I tried it - also I don't see any class called `thing` by itself - there are tags such as `thing_id` - Is it mandatory to do it via apps script for you? Because I have a couple other really easy ways to import it directly into the sheet

Comment: Just tried the above code in a Google Sheets script and it worked for me. The class `thing` is on each div that contains a post in the HTML. Each div also has a unique id but I want to pull all posts, which is why I pulled by class name. I tried other built-in functions in Google Sheets (e.g. `IMPORTFEED`) but it couldn't give me specific values I wanted like "rank" or "likes" so I decided to make this script. If you have other methods let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found upon playing with importXML (my usual way of doing this) - for some reason I cannot narrow down - it DOES appear to randomly stall out and return null for a few minutes - so I'm guessing the issue with your thing is not the code but that the site or google temporarily blocks/won't return the data -

however I found the JSON endpoint to the piece you want - and I noticed that when XML went down - the JSON didnt.

You can take that and fix it to push your own array of topics/urls - I just left it for one link for now to show you how the URL breaks down and where it should be modified:

The URL is `'https://www.reddit.com/r/news/hot.json?raw_json=1&subredditName=news&sort=top&t=day&feature=link_preview&sr_detail=true&app=mweb-client`

`News` is mentioned in 2 places so just modify all your URLs to follow that method - you can easily load that javascript in a browser to see all the fields available

Also the portion `hot.json` is where you can change whether you want the ranked list (called hot), or new,top,promoted, etc. you just change that keyword.

Score is the same as the upvotes/likes

```
function getSubReddit() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //get Active sheet
  var subject = 'news';
  var url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/' + subject + '/hot.json?raw_json=1&subredditName=' + subject + '&sort=top&t=day&feature=link_preview&sr_detail=true&app=mweb-client'; //json endpoint for data

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get api endpoint
  var json = response.getContentText(); // get the response content as text
  var redditData = JSON.parse(json); //parse text into json

  Logger.log(redditData); //log data to logger to check

  //create empty array to hold data points
  var statsRows = [];
  var date = new Date(); //create new date for timestamp


    //The following lines push the parsed json into empty stats array
    for (var j=0;j<25;j++){      
    for (var i =0;i<25;i++){
    var stats=[];

    stats.push(date);//timestamp 
    stats.push(i+1);
    stats.push(redditData.data.children[i].data.score); //score
    stats.push(redditData.data.children[i].data.title); //title
    stats.push(redditData.data.children[i].data.url); //article url
  // stats.push('http://www.reddit.com' + redditData.data.children[i].data.permalink); //reddit permalink

  statsRows.push(stats)

    }
      //append the stats array to the active sheet
      sheet.appendRow(statsRows[j])
  }


}
```

[image]